# RMAN Backup Compression

Tags: oracle, rman

SQL Server has built-in database backup compression. Is there an easy way to compress RMAN backups? Does it work well? Is restoring from a compressed backup straight forward? Is it even recommended? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compressing backups is straightforward, and restoring from compressed backups is transparent. There is a tradeoff in terms of performance, since compression requires additional CPU overhead; you'll have to decide what works best for you in your situation. Any compression option other than the basic/default (i.e. any use of the Advanced Compression Option) requires additional licensing.

See the full documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/backing-up-database.html#GUID-E0D30989-9477-45DD-8FE1-367BDD0A7A8E

> Making Compressed Backups
>
> When creating backup sets, you can use RMAN
> support for binary compression of backup sets by including the `AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET` option to the `BACKUP` command.
>
> RMAN compresses the backup set contents before writing them to disk.
> The details of which binary compression level is used are
> automatically recorded in the backup set. There is no need to
> explicitly mention the type of compression used or how to decompress
> the backup set in the recovery operation.
>
> Binary compression creates some performance overhead during backup and
> restore operations. Binary compression consumes CPU resources, so do
> not routinely schedule compressed backups when CPU usage is high.
> However, the following circumstances may warrant paying the
> performance penalty:
>
> - You are using disk-based backups when disk space in your fast recovery
>   area or other disk-based backup destination is limited.
> - You are performing your backups to some device over a network when
>   reduced network bandwidth is more important than CPU usage.
> - You are using some archival backup media such as CD or DVD, where
>   reducing backup sizes saves on media costs and archival storage.
>
> Example 9-7 Making Compressed Backups
>
> This example backs up the entire database and archived logs to the
> configured default backup destination (disk or tape), producing
> compressed backup sets.
>
> ```
> BACKUP    
>     AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET
>     DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
> ```

Comment: While this seems to have worked (backup completed successfully with no errors), I'm not sure it actually compressed the backup. I will do some more investigation. Thanks.

Comment: @Darrell yes it does compress. 700 MB compressed  vs 3.5 GB uncompressed backup of the same db